# How to solve new line problem in tessaract ocr?

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

I have an image with text in it. I used ocr to scan that image and I got the text correctly. There is just one problem: If there is a new line ocr won't leave space between two words.

```
img = cv2.imread('cropped.png')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
ret_str = ""
for letter in result:
    if letter.isalnum() or letter == " ":
        ret_str += letter.lower()
c_list = ret_str.strip()
print(c_list)
```

Output:

```
['gundam builddivers']
```

As you can see there is no space between `build` and `divers` in first element.

Image:

[image]

Comment: Is this the correct image? It says Onmyoji: Heian Monogatari, not something about Gundam Build Divers?

Comment: Sorry solved it now

Comment: What is the output of `print(result)`?

Comment: `Gundam Build\nDivers` <- Output

Comment: Okay I solved it seems I ignored the '\n' back there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
img = cv2.imread('cropped.png')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
result = result.replace("\n", " ")
ret_str = ""
for letter in result:
    if letter.isalnum() or letter == " ":
        ret_str += letter.lower()
c_list = ret_str.strip()
print(c_list)
```

Adding .replace() is the solution